# Htaccess rewrite rule exclude file with extension in the name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have used the following rewrite rule for a page:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.]*)$ description.php/$1
```

I want to match the url like "domain/user_name" which should open the description page.

But, with my current rule, when i am trying to access "abc.php" file, it is also showing the description.php which is different from abc.php file.

Can anyone suggest the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak regex of your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ description.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: adding [L] flag, does not work for any of any of my request. All sending the request to description.php page and i already added the Rewritecond.

Comment: Your comment is vague. `L` has nothing to do with your problem but updated regex is the issue. It is better you paste full .htaccess in question and also write what is the full URL for this it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: My question is totally different. How i can prevent the .php extension url to match  my rewrite url? While [L] prevent from further matching of rewrite rule. So, i don't think adding [L] flag will fix my problem.

Comment: You're again mistaken. Did I even mention that adding `L` will fix your problem. Better you forget about `L` and answer the questions I asked in previous comment.

Comment: Change is use of this regex in my answer `^([\w-]+)/?$` which will NOT match any file with dot in it.

Comment: i need that period (.) in my rule